# Access main profile in-app purchases from Android restricted profile

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

In my app I allow users to buy additional content via in-app purchases. However some users complain that if you create a restricted profile for main account that has purchase, then purchases don't appear in restricted profile. I checked, Google Play Billing API returns no purchases from within restricted profile and it's impossible to access main users data in the app.

I know some developers were able to achieve this, but don't understand how. I hope not by storing purchase information on SD card, that sounds awful.

Was anyone able to solve the problem?

Comment: When you tested, did you setup the restricted user to have Accounts access at all?  Right now the Accounts functionality is device wide, so if the device owner grants access to Accounts to the restricted user, they should have access to all owner account details; though they still will not have access to app specific data for the other user.

Comment: I allowed access to com.google accounts in manifest. So all Google accounts are accessible via AccountManager, but billing v3 API still returns empty purchase list when called under RM.

Comment: better to ask on google android group

Comment: Can you post your manifest as well as code which is using the Google Play Billing API?

Comment: Any progress on this? Or instructions for how the user can access IAP from a restricted account? Minecraft doesn't manage to pull this off. I now own a Texture pack, and the child can't use it.